# In the cases where equality comparisons would give the same result as strict equality comparisons, which of the two should be used?

Tags: php, coding-style, operators

To use an example, should it be `$name == "John Doe"` or `$name === "John Doe"`?

I'd guess that equality comparisons would perform worse as they would do some kind of type casting.

p.s. I know that the performance gain of choosing one over the other would be negligible, if any. It's a question of principle.

Comment: I guess it depends on how exact you need the comparison to be? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Pekka웃, I'm interested in the cases when both would give the same result (see the example in the question).

Comment: @Pekka웃, Would you care to write an answer? I'm sure you'd have some thoughts on the subject.

Comment: I can't think of anything meaningful to say right now that hasn't been said already. Maybe something occurs to me later. There may be edge cases in conversion, eg. when comparing against values that could be boolean (`1` etc.), as has already been said...  [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463465/in-the-cases-where-equality-comparisons-would-give-the-same-result-as-strict-equ#comment20153490_14463558) is an interesting argument in favour of strict comparisons, though - if your code base is so clean that you can put it into practice.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to check for === in most of your code, if you carefully live with the fact that you're not using a strongly typed language, but that should be a constant think when you write PHP code.

I usually use ==, reserving === to what the PHP manual suggests (i.e. strpos() calls and similars).

Here's some empirical benchmarks I run. Maybe I should switch to === ;-)

```
$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    if("1" === 1); 
}

$end = microtime(true);

echo number_format($end - $start,5,',','.') . " seconds";

// 0,06117 seconds for "thestring" === "thestring"
// 0,07601 seconds for "thestring" == "thestring"

// 0,05154 seconds for "1" === 1
// 0,09041 seconds for "1" == 1
```

Comment: The question concerns only cases where both would give the same result (see the example). It does not concern general use.

Comment: `==` seems to be a bit more complicated as it must do some kind of type casting. Do you agree and if yes, why would you usually use the complicated and not the simple?

Comment: Well, you answered by yourself. I will use it only if I need (for example) a value to be truely 0 and not false `if($response === 0)`

Comment: Answering your question: === does **not** typecasting. The manual is pretty clear. "If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. **The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is ===** or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value."

Comment: Having said that, why would you usually use the comparison operator that uses type casting (`==`) and not the one that doesn't (`===`)?

Comment: Really don't know, maybe wrong habits, basically when you start learning PHP EVERYONE tells you that to compare stuff you have to use "==". The real question is, how much does it costs typecasting? I did some benchmarks, I added the results to my answer.

Comment: `==` is used when you do not know the type of the values compared, eg. string with a number -- `if($str == $num)` where $str = '5' and $num = 5. When you want to compare their types as well(strict), you use `===`. Over the years, I have learnt that using `===` is better as in, most cases as a programmer, you do know the types you are comparing, and a strict programming practice is always better in the long run (more efficient, less errors).

Comment: Well, for the code I usually write I know 99.9% of the times what kind of value I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I always choose the strictest that works, on the premise I can prevent some logical error during a future change that would go otherwise undetected.  I have yet to feel bad about that procedure.

Answer (score 0):

`===` checks for `type` as well, besides equality. Here's the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for comparison operators.

As mentioned in a comment, I edited my answer,

`==` is used when you do not know the type of the values compared, eg. string with a number -- `if($str == $num)` where $str = '5' and $num = 5. When you want to compare their types as well(strict), you use `===`. Over the years, I have learnt that using `===` is better as in, most cases as a programmer, you do know the types you are comparing, and a strict programming practice is always better in the long run (more efficient, less errors).

Comment: what do you mean by `Identity`?

Comment: @Ascherer because, first it is a comment. and second, the OP specified that === is an identity checker, so to say it checks for types is nonsense.

Comment: I did not down-vote ... but it does not answer the OP question, so a down-vote makes sense

Comment: This is a subjective question, that doesnt really have an answer,and @PHPNooB it DOES check type, as it says in the php documentation... He also provided documentation for the OP to read more on use cases between the two...

Comment: @Ascherer the OP said `===` is identity checker`!` Now, does it make sense to answer by saying "=== checks for type as well"?

Comment: @PHPNoob: Please read the manual and get your concepts right before down-voting.

Comment: @PHPNooB i don see "Identity" in the OP, just equality and strict. And still, giving a link to the doc, showing use cases between the two

Comment: @Ascherer: PHPNoob is seeing/reading words that are not mentioned :)

Comment: To all: I edited the subject and changed "identity" into "strict equality" because that case is called so in terminology. So son't blame @PHPNooB

Comment: @coder1984 I think we can all agree, that you were NOT seeying identity was written before it was edited. But, you just run to make some points and didn't care to read about the title at all

Comment: @PHPNooB: Just because I haven't heard of that terminology before, doesn't make my answer wrong, probably just repetitive. So dont assume anything. Anyways, if you would have answered my first question, all the rest of the comments/confusion could have been avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on need.

```
$s = '0';
echo $s == '' ? 1 : 0;  // false

$s = 0;
echo $s == '' ? 1 : 0;  // true
echo $s === '' ? 1 : 0; // false
echo $s == false ? 1 : 0;  // true
echo $s === false ? 1 : 0; // false
```

But in your case, I guess it doesn't matter cos of these lines say all same.

```
$name = 'John Doe';
echo $name == 'John Doe' ? 1 : 0;  // true
echo $name === 'John Doe' ? 1 : 0; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are checking a value against either

- a whole numeric value (be it a string or a number)
- anything that will directly evaluate to a boolean

you're good to go with the equality operator itself. However, if you don't want to be bothered with all these possibilities, I believe using a strict equality operator would be a better option.

```
$check = array(
    array(
        'check' => array('01234','1234',01234,1234),
        'against' => array('01234',1234,01234)
    ),
    array(
        'check' => array(0,'0',FALSE,NULL,'',array()),
        'against' => array(FALSE,'')
    ),
    array(
        'check' => array(1,'1',TRUE,'ab',array('a')),
        'against' => array(TRUE,1,'ab')
    )
);

function var2Str($var) {
    if (is_string($var)) return "'$var'";
    elseif (is_bool($var)) return $var ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    elseif (is_null($var)) return 'NULL';
    elseif (is_array($var)) return 'array('.implode(',',$var).')';
    return $var;
}

foreach ($check as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr['check'] as $ch) {
        $chStr = var2Str($ch);
        foreach ($arr['against'] as $ag) {
            $e1 = $ch == $ag ? 'true' : 'false';
            $e2 = $ch === $ag ? 'true' : 'false';
            echo "$chStr\t==\t" . var2Str($ag) . "\t--> <b>$e1</b>" . PHP_EOL;
            echo "$chStr\t===\t" . var2Str($ag) . "\t--> <b>$e2</b>" . PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Check the first 2 lines in the second block of the output:

> '1234'    ==  '01234' --> **true**
>   '1234'    === '01234' --> **false**